# linux spi driver CONFIG

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

am new in linux and kernel compiling. I would like to add SPI support in my device - its stm32f429-disco evaluation board with LCD. I have found whole project here: https://github.com/jserv/stm32f429-linux-builder, compiled it and it works ( kernel source is https://github.com/robutest/uclinux ), but I don't know how to set CONFIG_STM32_SPI1 flag ( https://github.com/robutest/uclinux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-stm32/spi.c line:45 ) in https://github.com/jserv/stm32f429-linux-builder/blob/master/configs/kernel_config.

I've checked https://github.com/robutest/uclinux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-stm32/Kconfig and https://github.com/robutest/uclinux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-stm32/Makefile and config flags looks ok. Adding manually CONFIG_SPI_STM32 and CONFIG_STM32_SPI1 to "kernel_config" doesn't work. Compiler removes both flags from this file.

Why CONFIG_STM32_SPIx and CONFIG_SPI_STM32 entries are not even visible like other entries "# CONFIG_STM32_USART1 is not set" in the original "kernel_config" file ( I also can't find STM32-SPI in 'make menuconfig' )?

Comment: *"Why CONFIG_STM32_SPIx and CONFIG_SPI_STM32 entries are not even visible..."* -- Since you found the **Kconfig** file, you need to learn how to extract information from it.  In each paragraph for the config item in question, look for the "depends on ..." line.  These are configuration symbols that have to be enabled in order for this item to be exposed.  You may have to backtrack to other directories/menuconfig levels to get to those dependent selections.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, I have found dependency and now everything is visible in menuconfig.

Answer (score 1):

From what you provide I suggest to add to your defconfig, namely `kernel_config` file from project you are using:

> CONFIG_SPI=y
>
> CONFIG_SPI_STM32=y
>
> CONFIG_STM32_SPI1=y

Comment: Explicit editing of the **.config** file is frowned upon and should not be encouraged.

Comment: I updated the post to explicitly mention which config to touch.